# Send data before start listening ServerFactory twisted

Tags: python-2.7, twisted

I'm building a server herd on twisted. I have this sample code:

```
class MyHandler(basic.LineReceiver):
    def lineReceived(self, line):
      self.factory.sendLine("Welcome!")
    def makeConnection(self, transport):
      # what should go in here?

factory = protocol.ServerFactory()
factory.protocol = MyHandler
application = service.Application("My server")
internet.TCPServer(3030, factory).setServiceParent(application)
```

Since it's a server herd I need to establish connection with the servers that are already running (say 2.2.2.2, port 3032), and send them some control information to let them know a new server is listening.
My understanding is that I have to use the socket I will be listening on to send this information, so the other servers can use it to send packets back.

I think I could override the makeConnection method that was inherited form BaseProtocol (which get's called before the server starts listening).
But what do I have to do inside that method to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, Twisted does not have "sockets".  The underlying implementation is TCP sockets, of course, but speaking in terms of Twisted `IProtocol`s and `ITransport`s and `IListeningPort`s can alleviate a lot of confusion.

However, you're confused. `makeConnection` is a method on `IProtocol`, and no protocols are created until something *connects* to the listening socket.  You can't send data to a "listening socket" (this is made clear by the `IListeningPort` interface, which has no method for doing that), only to a "connected socket", or `ITransport`.

So, your code sample here is a bit too minimal to provide any useful advice about it.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, time after I posted the question I realized there was something wrong about it, because the constructor doesn't get called until a connection is established. Plus, the server herd looks like a graph, and for some nodes I have to notify two or more servers, making it impossible to use the same "socket". So, I decided to use python's network functionality to do that. It's fairly simple to use anyway.

Comment: "use python's network functionality"?  What are you talking about?  Now I'm concerned that you've done something even weirder :).

Comment: I was thinking of using the socket library on the Python API to connect to my other servers instead of using the Twisted engine. However, I found something similar to what I needed in this [FAQ](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#HowdoImakeinputononeconnectionresultinoutputonanother). Which was sending flooding information to servers, and listening to clients with the same reactor. I just had to use reactor.connectTCP several times and then reactor.listenTCP to listen to clients.

Comment: Whew. Great, glad to hear you figured it out!